# Default .bowerrc pointing to wwwroot/lib in asp 5

Tags: asp.net, gulp, bower

Why is this a default point for an empty asp project in the .bowerrc file?

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/bower_components"
}
```

In most cases one would use gulp and create tasks to include only the requested files

```
gulp.src([
    'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
])
```

Thereby creating a cleaner wwwroot. The project.json file even includes an `exclude` for `"bower_components"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it initially was outside of the `wwwroot` folder, but developers who weren't used to this workflow (ie. using Grunt/Gulp to copy the relevant files) were getting confused. So they changed it to be inside the `wwwroot` folder.

Scott Hanselman has a good post about why they did this, and how to change it back to be being outside ...

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ControlHowYourBowerPackagesAreInstalledWithAGulpfileInASPNET5.aspx